# I can get the state of the parking brake by OBDII?

Tags: obd-ii, elm327

I do engine autostart. To get the data from the car I use the ELM327 OBDII Bluetooth adapter. 
We already got the engine speed (010C) and coolant temperature (0105). 
For safety, I still have the position of the parking brake and the gearbox.
It is possible to model Chevrolet?

Answer (score 0):

there is no standard obd2 command to get the parking brake status
However, if your vehicle uses the CAN bus protocol, you can peek at the can bus
I dont know the can id for the parking brake